Stretching a nav to the bottom of height differing pages
How can I ensure the nav stretches to the bottom of every page dynamically? I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML so forgive me if anything is obviously wrong. But I can't figure this out for the life of me. Codepen: https://codepen.io/kekprod/pen/QWRgrMq
I tried to use Height: auto and 100% but they don't work, and 100vh doesn't stretch the entire page
Here's what I desire: Image (The red is the column/nav beneath the menu stretching down to the bottom of all pages



* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #2c2513;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

header div:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 2em;
  /* border: green solid 1px; */
}

header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 5;
  font-size: 200%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* border: red solid 1px */
}

header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* border: blue solid 1px; */
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 350px;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: #ffda72;
  color: black;
  border-top: #2c2513 solid 1px;
}

nav {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  border: #2c2513 solid 1px;
  background-color: #bda666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

header img {
  width: 52%
}

main {
  background-color: #dbc077;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.smallbutton {
  width: 8%;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  display: inline;
  transform: translate(-.5em, .2em)
}

.banner img,
.contactusbanner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.middletext {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

.margin4text {
  margin: 3em;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.margin4text p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.shoesContainer1,
.shoesContainer2 {
  padding: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shoe-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 0
}

footer {
  background-color: #dbc077;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tip Toe Soles</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h2>TipToe Soles</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="mens.html">Men's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="womens.html">Women's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="wishlist.html">Wishlist</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/banner2.png" alt="Welcome banner"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="shopButtons">
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="mens.html"><img src="images/shopmens.png" alt="Shop Men's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="womens.html"><img src="images/shopwomens.png" alt="Shop Women's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin4text">
      <h1>What is TipToe Soles?</h1>
      <p>Hey there! Welcome to TipToe Soles - your new favorite spot for comfy kicks that won't break the bank. Based in Sydney, Australia, we're all about bringing you shoes that feel as good as they look. Whether you're 30 or 100, our daily wear collection
        is designed for your comfort and style needs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="products.html"><img src="images/banner3.png" alt="latest arrivals banner"></a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="middletext">Check out our latest arrivals, introducing the Sallys and Heavenlys!</h1>
    <div class="shoesContainer1">
      <a href="sallyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Black.png" alt="Sally Black womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="heavenlyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Heavenly_Black.png" alt="Heavenly Black womens shoes">
          <p>Heavenly Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="sallytans.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Tan.png" alt="Sally Tan womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Tans</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <a href="returnpolicies.html">Return Policies</a> | <a href="exchangepolicies.html">Exchange Policies</a> | <a href="deliverypolicies.html">Delivery Policies</a><br><br> &copy; Tip Toe Soles 2024
  </footer>
</body>

</html>




Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide debugging details in the question directly in the form of a [repro]. Note the warning that you received before posting, that links to codepens are only allowed as an extension but not as a replacement.

Have you tried height: 100% on the body? I've copied your Codepen over to a Stack Overflow snippet, we try and keep all the code here as links can go down and this site is meant to be a resource for people encountering similar problems in the future.

@ZachJensz never copy code from Codepens to StackOverflow. Codepens have copyrights. The only person allowed to copy the content to SO is the author himself. Please read the Meta topic about it.

@tacoshy Interesting, I hadn't considered the licencing ramifications. I've added the Codepen link back. I think your way of welcoming people to Stack Overflow is hostile and unhelpful, my intention was to actually be helpful instead of contributing to the site's toxic reputation

@ZachJensz there are strict guidelines that every user has to follow incl. new users. Otherwise, the site can't focus on quality content but will be flooded with low-quality questions and answers. The only thing you can do to help the community is by sticking to those guidelines and linking them to bring it to the users attention. There are reviews templates. You're not helping anyone by causing legal issues.

My mistake, code has been shortened and added to snippet

Never align elements next to each other with float. float is for floating a block within flow-text such as an image within a newspaper. What you actually should use here to align the nav and main next to each other is by using CSS-Grid: display: grid.
For responsive reasons so that your navbar is not cut off on small screens I used 2 columns: grid-template-columns: minmax(15%, auto) 1fr; That way the navbar will be at least 15% wide but grow to be fully visible if needed. The main takes 1fr (1 fraction)  width and will occupy the remaining space. 
Both the header and footer using grid-column: span 2; to occupy both columns.
I also removed a few unnecessary CSS lines.


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(15%, auto) 1fr;
}

header {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #2c2513;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

header img {
  width: 52%
}

header div:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 2em;
  /* border: green solid 1px; */
}

header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 5;
  font-size: 200%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* border: red solid 1px */
}

header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* border: blue solid 1px; */
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 350px;
}

nav {
  border: #2c2513 solid 1px;
  background-color: #bda666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: #ffda72;
  color: black;
  border-top: #2c2513 solid 1px;
}

main {
  background-color: #dbc077;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.smallbutton {
  width: 8%;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  display: inline;
  transform: translate(-.5em, .2em)
}

.banner img,
.contactusbanner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.middletext {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

.margin4text {
  margin: 3em;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.margin4text p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.shoesContainer1,
.shoesContainer2 {
  padding: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shoe-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 0
}

footer {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #dbc077;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tip Toe Soles</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h2>TipToe Soles</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="mens.html">Men's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="womens.html">Women's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="wishlist.html">Wishlist</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/banner2.png" alt="Welcome banner"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="shopButtons">
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="mens.html"><img src="images/shopmens.png" alt="Shop Men's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="womens.html"><img src="images/shopwomens.png" alt="Shop Women's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin4text">
      <h1>What is TipToe Soles?</h1>
      <p>Hey there! Welcome to TipToe Soles - your new favorite spot for comfy kicks that won't break the bank. Based in Sydney, Australia, we're all about bringing you shoes that feel as good as they look. Whether you're 30 or 100, our daily wear collection
        is designed for your comfort and style needs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="products.html"><img src="images/banner3.png" alt="latest arrivals banner"></a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="middletext">Check out our latest arrivals, introducing the Sallys and Heavenlys!</h1>
    <div class="shoesContainer1">
      <a href="sallyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Black.png" alt="Sally Black womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="heavenlyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Heavenly_Black.png" alt="Heavenly Black womens shoes">
          <p>Heavenly Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="sallytans.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Tan.png" alt="Sally Tan womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Tans</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <a href="returnpolicies.html">Return Policies</a> | <a href="exchangepolicies.html">Exchange Policies</a> | <a href="deliverypolicies.html">Delivery Policies</a><br><br> &copy; Tip Toe Soles 2024
  </footer>
</body>

</html>



PS: I reordered your CSS. For readability you should list your selectors in the order of their appearance and group them that way. you had a header selector somewhere below the main and the nav selector also somewhere below. It was harder to find them that way.

This looks like a perfect use-case for CSS Grid!
We use the following properties:
display: grid;
grid-template
grid-template-areas
grid-area
Let's start by defining the rows and columns of our grid on the <body>:
body {
  ...
  display: grid;

  /* 
     This creates a grid with 3 rows and 2 columns.
     The middle row and right column will try to expand to
     their maximum size and the ones set to `auto` will shrink
     to the size of their content.
     `minmax(15%, auto)` is used to make sure the nav is always
     at least 15% of the width.
  */
  grid-template: auto 1fr auto / minmax(15%, auto) 1fr;

  /*
    Next, we'll give a name to our newly created grid cells.
    Because we have 2 columns and want the header and footer to
    span across both columns, their name appears twice.
    The names used here are arbitrary, but they should describe
    what will be placed in that area to make it more readable.
  */
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "nav      body"
    "footer footer";
}

Now we need to tell CSS Grid which elements belong in the "areas" we defined above:
(Also, we'll remove the margin-left from <main> and width and float from <nav> since those aren't needed anymore)
header {
 grid-area: header;
}

nav {
 grid-area: nav;
}

main {
 grid-area: body;
}

footer {
 grid-area: footer;
}



* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr auto / auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "nav body"
    "footer footer";
}

header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #2c2513;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
  
  grid-area: header;
}

header div:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 2em;
  /* border: green solid 1px; */
}

header div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 5;
  font-size: 200%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* border: red solid 1px */
}

header div:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* border: blue solid 1px; */
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 350px;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: #ffda72;
  color: black;
  border-top: #2c2513 solid 1px;
}

nav {
  /* width: 15%; */
  border: #2c2513 solid 1px;
  background-color: #bda666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  
  grid-area: nav;
}

header img {
  width: 52%
}

main {
  background-color: #dbc077;
  /* margin-left: 15%; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  
  grid-area: body;
}

.smallbutton {
  width: 8%;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  display: inline;
  transform: translate(-.5em, .2em)
}

.banner img,
.contactusbanner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.middletext {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

.margin4text {
  margin: 3em;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.margin4text p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.shoesContainer1,
.shoesContainer2 {
  padding: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shoe-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 0
}

footer {
  background-color: #dbc077;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  
  grid-area: footer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tip Toe Soles</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h2>TipToe Soles</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="mens.html">Men's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="womens.html">Women's Shoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="wishlist.html">Wishlist</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/banner2.png" alt="Welcome banner"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="shopButtons">
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="mens.html"><img src="images/shopmens.png" alt="Shop Men's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-button">
        <a href="womens.html"><img src="images/shopwomens.png" alt="Shop Women's Shoes button"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin4text">
      <h1>What is TipToe Soles?</h1>
      <p>Hey there! Welcome to TipToe Soles - your new favorite spot for comfy kicks that won't break the bank. Based in Sydney, Australia, we're all about bringing you shoes that feel as good as they look. Whether you're 30 or 100, our daily wear collection
        is designed for your comfort and style needs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="products.html"><img src="images/banner3.png" alt="latest arrivals banner"></a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="middletext">Check out our latest arrivals, introducing the Sallys and Heavenlys!</h1>
    <div class="shoesContainer1">
      <a href="sallyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Black.png" alt="Sally Black womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="heavenlyblacks.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Heavenly_Black.png" alt="Heavenly Black womens shoes">
          <p>Heavenly Blacks</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="sallytans.html">
        <div class="shoe-item"><img src="images/Sally_Tan.png" alt="Sally Tan womens shoes">
          <p>Sally Tans</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <a href="returnpolicies.html">Return Policies</a> | <a href="exchangepolicies.html">Exchange Policies</a> | <a href="deliverypolicies.html">Delivery Policies</a><br><br> &copy; Tip Toe Soles 2024
  </footer>
</body>

</html>




you don't need grid-area-templates and define every grid-area manually. Using header, footer { grid-column: span 2; } is much shorter, easier, and does the same job.

Shorter, yes. Easier? Neither is particularly difficult.  Shorter isn't always better. I would argue that if you use grid-template-areas, you should define all of the areas that will be used in the grid. It's more readable this way (especially when working with more complex grids) because you can visually see what will be placed in each section and there are no drawbacks to this approach aside from a couple of extra characters.

Exactly, the keyword is more complex grids. Or grids where you completely need to order the placement and not follow the document flow. Both cases do not apply here.

I'm pretty sure the keywords were more readable and  no drawbacks to this approach, but okay.

readbility comes from not bloating something more then needed. Thats why it is more readable for more complex grids or when you need to reorder against the document flow. But it is not more readable when you just need to place 2 elements next to each other. There it is bloated and less readable.

I disagree. I think this approach is more readable even in this simple case. It makes it explicitly clear where each element is placed in the grid and can make it easier for someone with limited knowledge of CSS Grid (which the OP likely has) to understand what is going on.
